# (Edited) I'm trying to display text on EditText from which obtain from JSONArray then get by JSONObject

Tags: java, android

This is my UserInfo.java (Edited)

```
public class UserInfo extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
EditText name, email, password, mobilenumber, address,
        city, postcode, state;
Button update;
```

//  private JSONArray userinfo = null;

```
// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String USERINFO_URL = "http://192.168.1.10:1234/PMSS/userinfo.php";
private static final String UPDATEUSERINFO_URL = "http://192.168.1.10:1234/PMSS/updateuserinfo.php";
// ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String TAG_MOBILENUMBER = "mobilenumber";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
private static final String TAG_POSTCODE = "postcode";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_info);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.useridtext);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtext);
    mobilenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenumbertext);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addresstext);
    city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.citytext);
    postcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postcodetext);
    state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statetext);

    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Name = name.getText().toString();
            String Email = email.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            String MobileNumber = mobilenumber.getText().toString();
            String Address = address.getText().toString();
            String City = city.getText().toString();
            String PostCode = postcode.getText().toString();
            String State = state.getText().toString();
            new UpdateUser(Name, Email, Password, MobileNumber, Address,
                    City, PostCode, State).execute();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
    // loading the comments via AsyncTask
    new RetrieveUser().execute();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_info, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

String Name, Email, Password, MobileNumber, Address, City, PostCode, State;

public void updateJSONdata() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(UserInfo.this);
    String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
    // String post_username = "jiaweitan05@gmail.com";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", post_username));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");
        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(USERINFO_URL, "GET",
                params);

        // I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail."
        // (success==1)
        // before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
        // mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
        // available
        JSONArray userinfo = json
                .getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            JSONObject c = userinfo.getJSONObject(0);

            Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            Email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            Password = c.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
            MobileNumber = c.getString(TAG_MOBILENUMBER);
            Address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            City = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
            PostCode = c.getString(TAG_POSTCODE);
            State = c.getString(TAG_STATE);


        name.setText(Name);
        email.setText(Email);
        password.setText(Password);
        mobilenumber.setText(MobileNumber);
        address.setText(Address);
        city.setText(City);
        postcode.setText(PostCode);
        state.setText(State);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class RetrieveUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserInfo.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Info...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        updateJSONdata();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}

class UpdateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

    boolean failure = false;
    String res;
    int success;
    String Name, Email, Password, MobileNumber, Address, City, PostCode,
            State, Position = "hahaha", CardBalance = "3456";

    public UpdateUser(String Name, String Email, String Password,
            String MobileNumber, String Address, String City,
            String PostCode, String State) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.MobileNumber = MobileNumber;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.City = City;
        this.PostCode = PostCode;
        this.State = State;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserInfo.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating User Info...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", Name));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Email));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobilenumber", MobileNumber));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", Address));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postcode", PostCode));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", City));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", State));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", Position));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", CardBalance));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            // Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    UPDATEUSERINFO_URL, "POST", params2);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Update attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            return success;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (success != null && success == 1) {
            Log.d("User Updated!", res);
            Intent r = new Intent(UserInfo.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(r);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(
                    UserInfo.this,
                    res == null ? "Please enter the require field that marked with **"
                            : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Log.d("Update Failure!", "res: " + res);
            Toast.makeText(
                    UserInfo.this,
                    res == null ? "Please enter the require field that marked with **"
                            : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

}
}
```

This is my logcat  (Edited)

```
12-13 21:47:32.199: D/request!(1387): starting
12-13 21:47:35.629: E/JSON Parser(1387): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <h1>User of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-13 21:47:35.669: W/System.err(1387): org.json.JSONException: No value for name
12-13 21:47:35.679: W/System.err(1387):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at com.pmss.UserInfo.updateJSONdata(UserInfo.java:165)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at com.pmss.UserInfo$RetrieveUser.doInBackground(UserInfo.java:203)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at com.pmss.UserInfo$RetrieveUser.doInBackground(UserInfo.java:1)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-13 21:47:35.709: W/System.err(1387):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-13 21:48:09.449: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1387): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

What I'm trying to do is that When I click UserInfo interface, it will load the user details and place in every `EditText` provided in UserInfo interface. But somehow every `EditText` in my UserInfo interface does not display anything.
My coding don't have compilation error and runtime error

This is where I start my `SharedPreferences` in Login.java

```
if (success == 1) {

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString("email", Username);
    edit.commit();

}
```

Can anyone help me out? I check for 2 days but still don't know why `EditText` display nothing.

From the logcat it said, E/JSON Parser(971): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value User of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject ?? How should I solve it?

This is my JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

 // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String registerUrl, String method,
            String[] params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my userinfo.php

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
//initial query
    $query = "Select name, email, password, mobilenumber, address, city, postcode, state  FROM user WHERE email = :email ";

    $query_params = array(':email' => $_POST['email']);
//execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();


    if ($row) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
        $response["posts"]   = array();

                $post = array();
                do {

                    // $post = $row["position"];
                    // $post = $row["state"];
                    // array_push($response["posts"], $post);
                    array_push($response["posts"], $row);
                } while ($row = $stmt->fetch()); 

            die(json_encode($response));
    }

    else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
            die(json_encode($response));
    }

} 
else {
        ?>
        <h1>User Info</h1> 
        <form action="userinfo.php" method="post"> 
            Email:<br /> 
            <input type="email" name="email" value="" /> 
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Search User" /> 
        </form>
        <?php
}
```

Comment: you should initialize all of your strings, otherwise they all are potential nullPointerExceptions.

Comment: should I initialize all to null in which line?

Comment: you have a string "Name", you have not initialized it. Now suppose `c.getString(TAG_NAME);` is empty, then at the time you do `name.setText(Name);` it'll give you nullPointerException. because there is no value in String Name. what you should actually do for every string is `String Name="";` `String Email="";`. My suggesstion is you should also check for null empty values in your response before directly assigning them to your textviews or edittexts.

Comment: @VishwasSharma looks he got JSONException not NPE `name.setText(Name)` will not give NPE

Comment: @VishwasSharma http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/EditText.java. `name.setText(Name)` will not give you can see why in the link

Comment: @user3096526 can you open `http://192.168.1.10:1234/PMSS/userinfoupdate.php` in your browser. what do you see. I can't comment on each an every step. Post the json.

Comment: @Raghunandan Ah, i just remembered exception can occur, but while posting, forgot about which exception and because mostly initializing problems gives NPE so that was first thing which came to my mind. Sorry for mistake and thanks for correction. But still, initializations and empty checks for JSON should be there for a robust code...:)

Comment: @Raghunandan I see no errors and have html form appears

Comment: @Raghunandan this is the json of userinfo.php output `this is my json in php output `{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[[{"name":"Jiawei","email":"jiaweitan05@gmail.com","password":"123456abcd","mobilenumber":"0124331292","address":"Bunga Raya","city":"Bukit Beruang","postcode":"75450","state":"Melaka"}]]}``

Comment: @user3096526 what about the other json. first you are making 2 requests. I will update my code for the json you have provided. Which url json is the above json?

Comment: @Raghunandan private static final String USERINFO_URL = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:1234/PMSS/userinfo.php";

Comment: @user3096526 i din't ask for url. I asked for the json. you need to post the other json response and check the edit of my post

Comment: `12-13 21:47:35.629: E/JSON Parser(1387): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <h1>User of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` in my logcat dont have the json format already.. just have this JSON Parser TAG error

Comment: @user3096526 `java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` what you get is a string so if you try to convert it into a json object you get exception. <h1> looks like html to me. So log the full response and post it here. if you need further help. Commenting in bits will not help

Comment: I already edited my logcat, is it what you mean? because I don't know how to get json from logcat since I press UserInfo button, my logcat doesn not show anything about json format

Comment: @user3096526 if you can't post response i can only imagine and give you answer. What you get is a string. there is no json. So converting to json you will get exception. Find a way to post response or deal with the problem yourself. This is too much commenting. My last comment. I can't post how to extract response also. Read the docs or search on google

Answer (score 2):

You say you json

```
{ // json object
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Post Available!",
    "posts": [  // json array posts
        [       // json array node
            {   // json object node 
                "name": "Jiawei",  // string
                "email": "jiaweitan05@gmail.com",
                "password‌​": "123456abcd",
                "mobilenumber": "0124331292",
                "address": "Bunga Raya",
                "city": "Bukit Beruang",
                "postcode": "75450",
                "state": "Melaka"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

`[` represents JSONArray node

`{` represents JSONObject node

Assuming you have the above json

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(USERINFO_URL, "GET",
            params);
```

Now To parse

```
  String success =json.getString("success");
  String message= json.getString("message");
  JSONArray jar = json.getJSONArray("posts");
  JSONArray jr = jar.getJSONArray(0);
  JSONObject jb = jr.getJSONObject(0);
  String name = jb.getString("name");
  //similarly for email, password and so on.
```

Now the other json

```
[      // json array node
    { // json object node
        "address": "Bunga Raya", // string
        "mobilenumber": "0124331292",
        "email": "jiaweitan05@gmail.com",
        "name": "Jiawei",
        "state": "Melaka",
        "postcode": "75450",
        "password": "123456abcd",
        "city": "Bukit Beruang"
    }
]
```

The log says

```
org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

It means you are trying to convert a json array to json object.

Comment: you say return `JSONArray` in `JsonParser` in `makeHttpRequest` where issit? And I edited my question with added JSONParser.java

Comment: one of my code is `userinfo = jsonarray.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);` this line also canceled it?

Comment: @user3096526 1. post the json full. 2. i don't understand your previous comments. pls be clear in what you ask

Comment: please reply me fast... I really need help now since many errors in my `JSONParser.java` have many errors occurs if you told me to change the return type to JSONArray..

Comment: @user3096526 `json = sb.toString()`. WHat do you see in log if you log json `Log.i("...........",json);`. Reply fast!. pls be patient. respect others time. Have this `Log.i("...........",json);` in `getJSONFromUrl`. see the log and post it here.

Comment: @user3096526 post your full json response which will help solve your problem easily.

Comment: where should I put this `json = sb.toString()` ??

Comment: @user3096526 after this line of code `json = sb.toString()` in method `getJSONFromUrl` have this line of code `Log.i("...........",json)`. What this does is logs the full json response. Now what you need to do is look at logcat and post the same json response here. With this i can give you an answer easily.

Comment: U mean When I click UserInfo button then copy paste the logcat here?

Comment: @user3096526 can you post the json full? that is what is required. Open the link in the browser.copy paste the json in your post.

Comment: `12-13 20:41:19.429: E/JSON Parser(489): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <h1>User of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: what link actually? and paste JSONParser.java?

Comment: what I found is this `json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }`

I does not saw the word `Log.i("...........",json)`

Comment: Oh Ya somehow the code JSONArray and JSONObject you gave me works..just how come you know that `[      // json array node
    { // json object node
        "address": "Bunga Raya", // string
        "mobilenumber": "0124331292",
        "email": "jiaweitan05@gmail.com",
        "name": "Jiawei",
        "state": "Melaka",
        "postcode": "75450",
        "password": "123456abcd",
        "city": "Bukit Beruang"
    }
]`

Comment: @user3096526 coz you din't read the docs. You din't make an effort to understand. If you had you would not have asked this question in the first place. Pls read the docs. Understand then try to implement. Why do you keep commenting. Ask a new question if you have a problem I am fed up commenting.

Answer (score 0):

### Mistake:

Your response is JSONArray and you are trying to create a  JSONObject with received response.

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(USERINFO_URL, "POST", params);
```

One more eye opening sentence exception is giving: **"org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject"**.

### Solution:

```
JSONArray arrayJSON = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(USERINFO_URL, "POST", params);
```

Comment: once I change to this, it pop out one error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

this is actual json format

```
{"countrylist":[{"id":"241","country":" India"}]}
```

use json object like countylist

Comment: post ur json that php output

Comment: this is my json in php output `{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[[{"name":"Jiawei","email":"jiaweitan05@gmail.com","password":"123456abcd","mobilenumber":"0124331292","address":"Bunga Raya","city":"Bukit Beruang","postcode":"75450","state":"Melaka"}]]}`

Comment: create json object in that

Comment: where to create json object?

Comment: for example In php file output like that { "list":[{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Post Available!",
    "posts": [  // json array posts
        [       // json array node
            {   // json object node 
                "name": "Jiawei",  // string
                "email": "jiaweitan05@gmail.com",
                "password‌​": "123456abcd",
                "mobilenumber": "0124331292",
                "address": "Bunga Raya",
                "city": "Bukit Beruang",
                "postcode": "75450",
                "state": "Melaka"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
]}

Comment: i know the structure just that, how to create JSON Object in coding?

Comment: in php  for exapmle   <?php

 include 'connection.php';
 $query="SELECT * 
      FROM  `city` order by id ";

        // mysql_set_charset("UTF8");

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
    
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         
            
                 $posts[] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'city'=>$row['city'],'state_id'=>$row['state_id']);       
     }
       $json=json_encode(array("citylist" => $posts));
     echo $json;
?>